# Is it feasable to have DAL and BLL layers in a Mac OS X Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

I am developing a Mac OS X application using Objective-C and Xcode 4 and want to find out the best way of handling data access and undertaking business logic tasks without having to use CoreData.

I am from a .NET MVC background and would normally have my controller call through to a service layer (using a Repository Pattern) to return data that could be mapped to my View. This would work in a similar way to the traditional Business Logic and Data Access Layer.

However on the Mac most of my reading suggests that my Models and Controllers should share the responsibility of populating the Model with with data and undertake business and validation logic.

This seems to me a little restrictive and goes against the DRY principle as I may need to repeat some data access/business logic operations in other models thus having to write tha same bit of code again.

Therefore is it feasible to have a set of classes or external libraries that undertake business/data access logic (to a SQLite database) that can then be called from any controller? Therefore the Model will only contain data about itself and validation logic? Or does this go against the core MVC principles and ways of building applications on the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason not to use Core Data in this scenario? It's highly-optimized for persisting objects to and from the local filesystem. It also performs validation at the model level, results caching, notifications, etc.

Comment: Not really its just that my background is building systems using databases and building multi-tiered applications in .NET. I already know how to do this and just want to apply it to Cocoa rather than having to learn a new object graph framework which is going to extend an already tight project deadline. I did look into this when I first started the development but could not find any good tutorials for what I wanted on the subject. ie demonstrating CRUD operations with models etc. Thanks

Comment: I'd highly recommend taking another look at CoreData, as you'll need to build these features yourself, which takes time. There are only a few scenarios where using it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have decided to go with CoreData after a good play around. As you say its highly optimized and after an initial steep learning curve its well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a good idea to me. Putting your validation and business logic in your model classes is proper use of MVC, and having the data stored in an sqlite database (that the model classes talk to) is a commonly used methodology too.

I'm not sure if we're on the same page with terminology: if you use that design, your classes "that undertake business/data access logic (to a sqlite database) that can then be called from any controller" will in fact *be* model classes.

Comment: Thats the problem as if everything is stored in the model classes how do you go about getting collections of items from the database ie a list of users? It would seem incorrect of the User model class to get a list of users from the database based on criteria? However if this functionality doesn't belong in a model class but in a controller then I could possible have code duplication in other controllers that want to get a list of users. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You could have a single class for fetching, treated like a singleton. To use it (from your controller) you feed in some parameters and it returns a bunch of your model objects. Thus there's no code duplication because any controller that needs to fetch users can just talk to that singleton. Alternatively, just make a class method (as opposed to an instance method) on The User class that fetches data then creates and instantiates User objects. Both these approaches can be found in Apple APIs.